# How can I access the index of the C1FlexGrid ComboList in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, componentone, c1flexgrid

I am required to access the items of the C1FlexGrid's ComboList. Here's how it's supposed to be used in accordance to their documentation:

```
Dim myList As String
myList = "|itemOne" & _ 
         "|itemTwo" & _ 
         "|itemThree"

'The following will add a ComboList cell editor for the specified column, on every row
Dim Col As Integer = 2
myFlexGrid.Cols(Col).ComboList = myList
```

Then, in order to read that value, I would do this:

```
Dim Row As Integer = 1
Dim SelectedItem As String = myFlexGrid(Row, Col)
```

It would return my itemOne string, and I would need to fire a **ComboCloseUp** event with conditionals based on that item. But I do not want to use the string as a condition because it will alter based on language.

I know that in VB6 implementation you were able to also assign and ID in the following manner:

```
myList = "#1; itemOne" & vbTab & "apple" & _ 
         "#2; itemTwo" & vbTab & "orange"
myFlexGrid.Cols(Col).ComboList = myList
```

You would be able to access that ID later, and the tab character would also render the ComboList multi-column and place whatever followed it on a separate column.

Has anyone dealt with this?

---

This is also my first question here, so I apologize for bad formatting.

Comment: Could you use whatever you use for the different languages for the conditionals?

Comment: That is maybe the first thing that comes to mind but I think it's bad practice.

Comment: It looks to me like the [ComboBoxEditor Class](https://help.grapecity.com/componentone/NetHelp/c1flexgrid/webframe.html#C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.ComboBoxEditor.html) example has what you need with the ListDictionary. I could be wrong.